# Default methods executed by Jetty/Tomcat while loading/reloading the .war

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, jetty

I have created a dynamic web Application for RESTful web Service using JAX-RS Jersey implementation and deployed as a .war file in a container ( works fine in both Tomcat and Jetty)
Next, the other requirement is when the web container loads the .war, I need one method to be called ( to check the location of 'myTemp' folder for the files in the same host machine and copy the files from within the .war file to the folder 'myTemp')

**So, just wanted to know if there is a way where Tomcat or Jetty executes some method on its own while loading/reloading the .war file OR any out of the box support provided by the container?**

Please help.

Regards,
FK

Answer (score 0):

Create a class of your own that implements [`javax.servlet.ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html).

Add to your `WEB-INF/web.xml` like this:

```xml
<listener>
   <listener-class>com.company.MyContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Then use the `contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent)` for when the web app context is being created, and `contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent)` for when the web app context is being unloaded.